# Upload multiple files using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I have the following code to upload files to a database in mysql:

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
  <label>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</label>
</div>
<div id="body">
     <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
<br /><br />

<?php
if(isset($_GET['success']))
{
    ?>
    <label>File Uploaded Successfully...  <a href="view.php">click here to view file.</a></label>
    <?php
}
else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
{
    ?>
    <label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>

    <?php
}
?>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

$file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$folder="uploads/";

// new file size in KB
$new_size = $file_size/1024;  
// new file size in KB

// make file name in lower case
$new_file_name = strtolower($file);
// make file name in lower case

$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('successfully uploaded');
    window.location.href='index.php?success';
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='index.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
}
}
?>
```

which works well, but only for individual file. I saw many tutorials, but I can not modify the code to allow upload multiple files at once. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow multiple file uplodes you need to set attribute `multiple="multiple"` on the file input with a name `file[]`. Or you can use separate inputs with a name `file[]` as well. Than to store values in database make a

```
 foreach($_FILES['filename']['name'] as $key=>$name){
     // store each file and write data to DB for each file
     //for example to get the name of file
     $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$key];
 }
```